# How to change border color of jquery Select2?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-select2

How can I change the border color of this. I generally got it from
[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60831923/20398610)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("select").select2();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.0.13/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.0.13/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>


<select id="select_page" style="width:200px;" class="operator" style="border: 2px solid red;">
  <option value="">Select a Page...</option>
  <option value="alpha">alpha</option>
  <option value="beta">beta</option>
  <option value="theta">theta</option>
  <option value="omega">omega</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Border of what? The select?

Comment: @bimbo1989 yes.

Comment: https://select2.org/appearance

Comment: As the documentation says, "The appearance of your Select2 controls can be customized via the standard HTML attributes".  See: [MDN border-style](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-style)

Comment: can also just use css `.select2 {width: 100%;} .select2-selection {border: 2px solid red;}`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to customize jquery select2 plugin - The jQuery replacement for select boxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31538734/how-to-customize-jquery-select2-plugin-the-jquery-replacement-for-select-boxes)

Answer (score 2):

You can style elements with CSS, so if you want every `select2-selection` class to have a certain `border-color`, you can add the following:

```
.select2-selection {
  border-color: green; /* example */
}
```